# updating workbook's internal worksheet list from inside module when new worksheets are created

Tags: vba, excel

The attached code is all located in the excel VBAProject's module. The code will scan thru all of the existing worksheets and retrieve data, sort it, and even create new worksheets if a sub-assembly is found.

The problems are:
(1) it will not perform any task on the newly created worksheets until it is re-ran. I think the issue has to do with forcing the workbook to update it's worksheet list each time it creates a new worksheet.
(2) the routine seems to add a worksheet at end of run that does not match the criteria defined for creating new worksheets. (i.e. sub-assembly numbers start with either 772, 993, 995, 996, or 997)

Note that there is disabled code in sections so that I can keep track of a few of the things that I have tried such as - 'ThisWorkbook.Save , etc...

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running out of hair :)

Code:

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim ws_iCount As Integer
Dim i As Variant
Dim myBOMValue As Variant
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iRowValue As Variant
Dim iRowL As Variant
Dim iCountA As Integer
Dim sShtName As String
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next 'Will continue if an error results
    If Not ws.Name = "Main" And Not ws.Name = "BOM" Then
        myBOMValue = ws.Name
        Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
        ' store sub-assembly name at cell C1 of active worksheet
        Range("C1").Value = ws.Name
        ' Cmd for system and application to do non-macro related events
        DoEvents
' Begin FishBowl Query for sub-assembly parts
            With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array("ODBC;DSN=Fishbowl;Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=###.###.###.###:C:\Fishbowl2\database\data\$$$$.FDB;CHARSET=NONE;;UID=GO"), Array("NE;Client=C:\Program Files\Fishbowl\odbc\fbclient32.dll;")), Destination:=Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
                ' @@ QueryTable commands START
                '   select BOM and retrieve data
                .CommandText = Array("SELECT BOM.NUM, PART.NUM, PART.DESCRIPTION, BOMITEM.QUANTITY" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "FROM BOMITEM" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "INNER JOIN BOM" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "ON BOMITEM.BOMID = BOM.ID" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "INNER JOIN PART" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "ON PART.ID = BOMITEM.PARTID" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "WHERE BOM.NUM Like '%" & myBOMValue & "%'" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Order BY Part.Num")
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                .Refresh
                ' @@ QueryTable commands END
            End With
        ' Cmd for system and application to do non-macro related events
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'   *********************
' Begin duplicate part number consolidation
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
            For iRow = 3 To iRowL
                If Cells(iRow, 2) = Cells((iRow + 1), 2) Then
                    iCountA = 0
                    Do While (Cells(iRow, 2) = Cells((iRow + 1), 2)) And (IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) = False)
                        iRowValue = (Cells(iRow, 4) + Cells((iRow + 1), 4))
                        Cells(iRow, 4) = iRowValue
                        Rows(iRow + 1).EntireRow.Delete
                        iCountA = iCountA + 1
                        If iCountA > 20 Then
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                        End If
                    Loop
                Else
                End If
            Next iRow
        ' Cmd for system and application to do non-macro related events
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ' Cmd for system and application to do non-macro related events
        DoEvents
'   *********************
' Reset variables and Begin checking for sub-assemblies
        iRow = 0
        iRowValue = 0
        iRowL = 0
        'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
        iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
            For iRow = 3 To iRowL
                sShtName = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
                If (InStr(1, Cells(iRow, 2).Value, "772") And Not WksExists(sShtName)) Then
                        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                        ActiveSheet.Name = sShtName
                        'Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
                        'ThisWorkbook.Save
                    ElseIf (InStr(1, Cells(iRow, 2).Value, "993") And Not WksExists(sShtName)) Then
                        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                        ActiveSheet.Name = sShtName
                        'Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
                        'ThisWorkbook.Save
                    ElseIf (InStr(1, Cells(iRow, 2).Value, "995") And Not WksExists(sShtName)) Then
                        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                        ActiveSheet.Name = sShtName
                        'Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
                        'ThisWorkbook.Save
                    ElseIf (InStr(1, Cells(iRow, 2).Value, "996") And Not WksExists(sShtName)) Then
                        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                        ActiveSheet.Name = sShtName
                        'Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
                        'ThisWorkbook.Save
                    ElseIf (InStr(1, Cells(iRow, 2).Value, "997") And Not WksExists(sShtName)) Then
                        Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                        ActiveSheet.Name = sShtName
                        'Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
                        'ThisWorkbook.Save
                    Else
                End If
            'change active workbook sheet
            Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
            sShtName = ""
            Next iRow
    Else
    End If
    ' Cmd for system and application to do non-macro related events
    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '  change active workbook sheet back to Main
    Sheets("Main").Activate
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: In general you want to try to avoid modifying any collection while you're at the same time looping over it.  You might find it easier to add all of the existing sheets to a Collection, and then process that by taking the first item from it, processing it and then removing it from the collection.  End the loop when you've removed all items from the collection.  If you add new sheet during the processing then add that to the Collection to ensure it'll also get processed.

Comment: @TimWilliams - shouldn't that be an answer? Or do you feel it's not detailed enough?

Comment: @ChipsLetten - I will look at wring a simple demo of that approach...

Answer (score 1):

In general you want to try to avoid modifying any collection while you're at the same time looping over it.

You might find it easier to add all of the existing sheets to a `Collection`, and then process that by taking the first item from it, processing it and then removing it from the collection. End the loop when you've removed all items from the collection.

If you add one or more new sheets during the processing, then add those to the Collection to ensure they'll also get processed.

Here's a simple example of that approach:

```
Sub TestSheetLoop()
Dim colSheets As New Collection
Dim sht As Worksheet, shtNew As Worksheet

    'grab all existing sheets
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        colSheets.Add sht
    Next sht

    Do While colSheets.Count > 0

        Set sht = colSheets(1)
        Debug.Print sht.Name
        '*********************
        '...process this sheet
        '*********************

        'adding a new sheet...
        If sht.Name = "Sheet2" Then
            Set shtNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
            shtNew.Name = "New sheet"
            'add to collection
            colSheets.Add shtNew
        End If

        'remove the sheet we just processed
        colSheets.Remove (1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I hadn't thought about the collection option. I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. The collection option works but still requires macro to be ran multiple times if new sheets are created in the previous run. I think I will try a different tack and create an auto-run macro that checks for data in each worksheet and then calls the retrieval macro if no data is present. At least then I can use an event to trigger it as often as needed without user intervention.

Comment: The basic code I posted should not require multiple runs, so there is something else going on which I'm not seeing.